# How to attach properties to a function in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write stateless React.js component `myView`, keeping syntax as short as possible. But cant understand syntax for exporting default function, while having an object attached to it. Consider following example `myView.js`:

```
const myView = {
    Foo: (props) => (<snap>{props.foo}</snap>),
    Bar: (props) => (<snap>{props.bar}</snap>),
    'default': (props) => (<>
        <myView.Foo {...props} />
        <myView.Bar {...props} />
     </>)
}

module.exports = myView;
```

To render it, I just want to recall it simply from `App` class in `myApp.js`:

```
import myView from './myView';
...
render() { return(<myView foo="foo" bar="bar" />); }
```

But this short syntax is not working. How would you offer to rewrite `myView.js', to keep things short, nice and working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With es6 `import / export` you can't normally use `module.exports`.
(It can work if you modify your build setup)
You need to specify the exports with [export statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

`myView.js`:

```
export const Foo = (props) => (<snap>{props.foo}</snap>);
export const Bar = (props) => (<snap>{props.bar}</snap>);

export default (props) => (<>
        <Foo {...props} />
        <Bar {...props} />
     </>);
```

Edit: If you only want 1 export statement, you could also write it like this:

```
const Foo = (props) => (<snap>{props.foo}</snap>);
const Bar = (props) => (<snap>{props.bar}</snap>);
const def = (props) => (<>
        <Foo {...props} />
        <Bar {...props} />
     </>);
export { Foo, Bar, def as default };
```

Comment: That depends on the project setup. Both could work together, but OP's project is probably not configured for it, so you're probably pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, may I add you a little restriction? You may not write `export` word more than two times (but you still need to export both foo, bar, and have default export :)

Comment: In other words, on the app side, you need to have access all three things: myView, myView.Foo and myView.Bar, but the challenge limits you on using word `export` to no more than 2 times (better 1 time), and using classes is not wanted (because no object instance is actually required here)

Comment: @EmileBergeron true, i assumed that part. I edited the wording to make this more clear

Comment: @xakepp35 I added an example for only using 1 export statement, no classes.